# MySQL select rows based on previous query

Tags: php, mysql

```
$clicks = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['clicks']);
$modifier = 10*$clicks;

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY freshness LIMIT $modifier,10");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $posts[] = $row;
}

$result2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY time WHERE ????");

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
    $comments[] = $row2;
}
```

For `$result2`, how can I select `WHERE` of each of the 10 post IDs (i.e. `$row['id']`) from `$result`? Otherwise I'd be selecting every single comment in the table unnecessarily.

Comment: How about using a `join` and just getting everything in one query?

Comment: Could you explain further what that is? I'm new to PHP/MySQL

Comment: Can you please share the structure of your tables?

Comment: @Mureinik `posts` has columns `id` plus a whole bunch of other columns which I'm assuming are irrelevant for this; `comments` also has `id` as well as `post_id` which is the same as `id` in `posts` (they're linked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example do the following, using your current code and an `IN` clause for MySQL.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    // Here we use the ID for the array key.
    $posts[$row['id']] = $row;
}

// Here we get the array keys and implode the IDs into a comma-separated list.

$row_ids = implode(',', array_keys($posts));

// And here we plug it into an `IN` statement.

$result2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id IN ({$row_ids}) ORDER BY `time`");

// May want to change the 'time' above into a non-reserved word...

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
    // Here we add the comments into arrays associated by post_id.
    $comments[$row2['post_id']][] = $row2;
}
```

Yes I realize that crafting a JOIN instead would look sexy. It could also accrue a lot of overhead. Now benchmarking the scenarios... For which I've created sample tables for posts (1000 posts) and comments (5000 comments with a random post's ID) for benchmarking. (Index on the timestamps.)

**Case 1:** First selecting 50 posts ordered by date. Then selecting all their comments using `IN` with post IDs as above, again ordered by date. (Returns 50 posts and 268 comments on each loop with this test data.) Result: 1000 loops in 3.0888 sec (avg. 0.0030888 sec).

**Case 2:** Using the `JOIN` example by @OllyTeneriffe. (I set `LIMIT` to 268 to match Case 1's data volume, "cheating" on the limit clause problem noted in the comments.) Results fetched in a single loop. Result: 1000 loops in 25.7868 sec (avg. 0.0257868 sec).

Repeated tests with `LIMIT 200` (yielding 200 posts + 971 comments). **Case 1:** 8.2992 sec (avg. 0.0082992 sec). **Case 2:** 33.5089 sec (avg. 0.0335089). The results are not as sexy as the join may look. In this case, the "simple" approach is an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: You will also want to have the `ORDER BY` after the `WHERE`... Edited above.

Comment: This is giving me an error `mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean` starting here `while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
 $comments[] = $row2;
}`

Comment: i don't know why any one would upvote this its a far inferior option to using a join.

Comment: @frosty I am right now benchmarking an almost-identical query, works fine. You may want to change `time` into something else or put it inside backticks, since it's a reserved MySQL keyword. Otherwise, use `mysqli_error()` please, so you can see where things go wrong. @Dagon and what about performance-wise? Care to sketch in a sample join that doesn't accrue crazy over-head if he wants to `SELECT *` and needs to e.g. join dozens of comments per each post?

Comment: I got it to work, it was the most silly error because I was converting some things to simpler terms for the example here.

Comment: Only one issue - I'm retrieving the data with $.getJSON and using function(data) so that I'm doing data.posts.forEach and data.comments.forEach (arrays) -- your example does something different. Yours: http://puu.sh/iguAV/aacc26b8f7.png - Before: http://puu.sh/iguC8/606ee7a56c.png - what can I do to convert it back to an array?

Comment: @Dagon I've added benchmark results. The inferior option seems to be an order of magnitude better as far as performance. Unless you have a join approach that does this both elegantly and quickly. Would certainly love to see one, but I doubt it's possible to do this as efficiently with a JOIN. The "beauty" of two separate precise queries is zero overhead; the `IN` in the second can use a primary index; and it really is a very minimal add to the code.

Comment: @frosty this sounds like a separate question. Based on what you've posted above, I can only speak of the SQL and the PHP for fetching the data. I have no idea what you may do with the data afterwards, or where jQuery comes in down the line. From the above, you will certainly get two arrays; one called `$posts` and another called `$comments`.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway, and the benchmarks are very useful to know your method is much quicker. I'll be sure to ask it as another question.

Comment: I've now edited the comments array to have it bundle the comments per post into an associative array. Do post the link in here somewhere when you have your follow-up question ready. (I'm already getting a nag about "extended discussions in comments"...)

Answer (score 3):

Why not do this all in a single query?

```
 $modifier = 10*$clicks;

 $query = "SELECT *
    FROM posts 
    INNER JOIN comments
    ON posts.id = comments.post_id
    ORDER BY posts.freshness 
    LIMIT '$modifier'";
```

Comment: I think this is only selecting one comment per post, rather than all the comments for each post.

Comment: It does give you all the comments. However, since the rows are joined, you will have rows with fields like: post:1+comment:1, post:1+comment:2, etc. and the LIMIT clause here will not limit the number of *posts*, as you might expect, but rather it would chop whenever LIMIT amount of *comments* are matched. Suppose your first post has 100 comments and you want to fetch 50 posts using LIMIT. With this query, you will not even get all the comments to your first post, much less the remaining posts.